# php array foreach results with selected values

Tags: php, arrays, api, email, cpanel

I have a PHP array as follows:

```
    Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [_diskquota] => 524288000
            [_diskused] => 0
            [diskquota] => 500
            [diskused] => 0
            [diskusedpercent] => 0
            [diskusedpercent20] => 0
            [domain] => domain1.com
            [email] => aaa@domain1.com
            [humandiskquota] => 500 MB
            [humandiskused] => None
            [login] => aaa@domain1.com
            [mtime] => 1378636684
            [txtdiskquota] => 500
            [user] => aaa
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [_diskquota] => 0
            [_diskused] => 0
            [diskquota] => unlimited
            [diskused] => 0
            [diskusedpercent] => 0
            [diskusedpercent20] => 0
            [domain] => domain2.com
            [email] => ddd@domain2.com
            [humandiskquota] => None
            [humandiskused] => None
            [login] => ddd@domain2.com
            [mtime] => 1378636684
            [txtdiskquota] => unlimited
            [user] => ddd
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [_diskquota] => 104857600
            [_diskused] => 0
            [diskquota] => 100
            [diskused] => 0
            [diskusedpercent] => 0
            [diskusedpercent20] => 0
            [domain] => domain3.com
            [email] => sss@domain3.com
            [humandiskquota] => 100 MB
            [humandiskused] => None
            [login] => sss@domain3.com
            [mtime] => 1378636684
            [txtdiskquota] => 100
            [user] => sss
        )
)
```

How can I get results like this in php foreach? (I don't want in list other values)

email | humandiskquota | humandiskused

my code for try. foreach is woiking but I can't get just email value from array.

```
foreach ($d as $arr => $key)
{
foreach ($key as $k => $v)
{
//echo "$k: $v<br>";
echo $email=$k['email'].' | ';
echo $email=$v['email'].' | ';
echo $email=$v->email.' | ';
echo $email=$k->email.' | ';
}
echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) loops here. The following should work:

```
foreach ($d as $key => $data) {
    $email[] = $data['email'];

    echo $data['email']. ' | ' . 
         $data['humandiskquota'] . ' | ' . 
         $data['humandiskused'];

    echo '<br/>';
}
//print_r($email);
```

Output:

```
aaa@domain1.com | 500 MB | None
ddd@domain2.com | None | None
sss@domain3.com | 100 MB | None
```

### [**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/0SFALqjs)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply with one `foreach`:

```
foreach ($d as $array){
  echo "{$array['email']} | {$array['humandiskquota']} | {$array['humandiskused']} <br/>" ;
}
```